# Staying for 8-12 months on Visit Visa

Tags: visa, malaysia

A quick question what What is the best and easiest way to stay in Malaysia for 8-12 months without getting going back to home.

I heard we can do via crossing borders , if. If we do in that way we need visa of Singapore or Thai Thailand, if yes which category visa we need visit or transit.

Also, it will be on arrival visa or i need to get that visa from malaysia ?

Also if there is any further way to do that so Malaysia ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your nationality, it's difficult to point you in the right direction. However, the answer to your basic visa question can be found on this [Malaysia tourism guide](http://www.2malaysia.com/visa.htm), which outlines visa and visa-on-arrival options, country by country, including exceptions.

And [PaperStoneScissors](https://www.tripadvisor.com/members-forums/PaperStoneScissors) offered this response yesterday to your query on the [TripAdvisor Malaysia forum](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293951-i7006-k9944628-Staying_for_8_12_months_on_Visit_Visa-Malaysia.html)

> To live in Malaysia as a foreigner you need either a work permit or MM2H (Malaysia My Second Home) Visa. Neither are available to you. Trying to live here by doing visa runs may get you stopped by immigration and eventually you will be refused entry. Not a good idea to try it.